# TCP Window Scaling in Linux server - possible side effects

Tags: windows, linux, networking, tcp

It says here -

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option#Linux

"Because many routers and firewalls do not properly implement TCP Window Scaling, it can cause a user's Internet connection to malfunction intermittently for a few minutes, then appear to start working again for no reason.

There is also an issue if a firewall doesn't support the TCP extensions."

As i understand, **TCP Window Scalling** bad influence on performance of the channel when many short connections (web).

Disable **TCP Window Scaling** on Linux server, or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the Wikipedia article you cited considerably overstates the case. The Microsoft Knowledge Base article it links to only cites 5 devices with this problem. That isn't 'many'.

And you need to consider that the problem is caused by Windows Vista defaulting to an enormous window scale of 8, enough to describe a window of 64k << 8 = 16MB, a ridiculously large number. Linux may or may not trigger it at all: at present you have zero evidence about that.

TCP window scaling does not cause 'bad performance [of] many short connections'. It causes *very good* performance on long lived connections.

I would place a lot more reliance on RFCs and vendor statements than on arbitrary Web sources; even Wikipedia. I corrected a major error in a TCP article there just this month.

Answer (score 0):

1)All TCP extensions including SACK,ECN etc. are negotiated between 3-WAY-Handshake process within client and server socket if either doesn't support any said extension then another peer just ignores those TCP extension during the the life cycle of that TCP Session. So there is no issue if your firewall or router not supports those extensions.

2)It is general practice that vendors implement window scaling based on AIMD principle.It is best practice to leave window scaling on its default enabled .

Comment: I don't know what you mean by (2). Window *scaling* is not implemented on the AIMD principle. The *receive eindow* itself and the *congestion window* are implemented on the AIMD principle. As you point out yourself in (1), window scaling is implemented in the connect handshake, once, so there is simply no opportunity to apply AIMD to it. I don't see why leaving window scaling at its default value is 'best practice'. What's it for if you can't use it?